# AppStore Search not finding my App when I enter a keyword defined in the App Metadata

Tags: ios, metadata, keyword-search

In iTunes Connect, under the Metadata section of my App., I define keywords that are then used by the AppStore & Apple Watch AppStore Search engines to find my App.

I perform a search on any of these keywords e.g. boat (See list of keywords as entered into iTUnes Connect, below) and my App. is not found, neither in the AppStore nor the Apple Watch AppStore.

It is only found if I enter the name of my App.

List of keywords in App MetaData = boat; yacht; cruise; sail

Please can someone explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the post has nothing to with programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try looking for your app using `keywords phrases.` If you can't find your app still then there can be many reasons like:

1. You might not have `performed enough research while doing ASO` because there is alot of competition for some of the keywords that you have mentioned here i.e for the keyword `boat` you are competing with 3000 iPhone apps and 3000 ipad apps(Resource: Sensor tower). So it is possible that you are not ranking for this keyword.
2. Your Keywords are separated by semicolons instead of commas  `boat; yacht; cruise; sail`.

Answer (score 1):

The app store operates just like any other search engine - your keywords and metadata have to be optimized to get the most out of it. However, if your app is in a very highly competitive genre then it becomes quite difficult to rank for your keywords.

Also, if your app has only just gone live then it is unlikely to return with keywords.